# Convert C# PBKDF2 using Rfc2898DeriveBytes to PHP

Tags: c#, php, wordpress, pbkdf2

Long story short have a membership system built in .NET that we are porting to WordPress and need to replicate the PBKDF2 encryption so users don't need to reset their passwords.

Using a know hashed password I've been able to replicate this in .NET easily, with the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var isValid = CheckPassword("#0zEZcD7uNmv", "5SyOX+Rbclzvvit3MEM2nBRaPVo2M7ZTs7n3znXTfyW4OhwTlJLvpcUlCryblgkQ");
}

public static int PBKDF2IterCount = 10000;
public static int PBKDF2SubkeyLength = 256 / 8; // 256 bits
public static int SaltSize = 128 / 8; // 128 bits

private static bool CheckPassword(string Password, string ExistingHashedPassword)
{
  byte[] saltAndPassword = Convert.FromBase64String(ExistingHashedPassword);
  byte[] salt = new byte[SaltSize];

  Array.Copy(saltAndPassword, 0, salt, 0, SaltSize);

  Console.WriteLine("--Salt--");
  Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(salt));

  string hashedPassword = HashPassword(Password, salt);

  Console.WriteLine("--HashedPassword--");
  Console.WriteLine(hashedPassword);

  return hashedPassword == ExistingHashedPassword;
}

private static string HashPassword(string Password, byte[] salt)
{
  byte[] hash = new byte[PBKDF2SubkeyLength];
  using (var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Password, salt, PBKDF2IterCount))
  {
    hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(PBKDF2SubkeyLength);
  }

  byte[] hashBytes = new byte[PBKDF2SubkeyLength + SaltSize];
  Array.Copy(salt, 0, hashBytes, 0, SaltSize);
  Array.Copy(hash, 0, hashBytes, SaltSize, PBKDF2SubkeyLength);

  string hashedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
  return hashedPassword;
}
```

The console app will produce the following:

```
--Salt--
5SyOX+Rbclzvvit3MEM2nA==
--HashedPassword--
5SyOX+Rbclzvvit3MEM2nBRaPVo2M7ZTs7n3znXTfyW4OhwTlJLvpcUlCryblgkQ
--IsValid--
True
```

However in the PHP side I can't get the same results. My code so far is below.

```
$mySalt = base64_decode('5SyOX+Rbclzvvit3MEM2nA==');
$dev = pbkdf2('sha1', '#0zEZcD7uNmv', $mySalt, 10000, 48, true);
$key = substr($dev, 0, 32); //Keylength: 32
$iv = substr($dev, 32, 16); // IV-length: 16

echo 'PHP<br/>';
echo 'PASS: '.base64_encode($dev).'<br/>';
echo 'SALT: '.base64_encode($iv).'<br/><br/>'; 

echo '.NET<br/>';
echo 'PASS: 5SyOX+Rbclzvvit3MEM2nBRaPVo2M7ZTs7n3znXTfyW4OhwTlJLvpcUlCryblgkQ<br/>';
echo 'SALT: 5SyOX+Rbclzvvit3MEM2nA==<br/><br/>'; 

function pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output = false)
{
    $algorithm = strtolower($algorithm);
    if(!in_array($algorithm, hash_algos(), true))
        die('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid hash algorithm.');
    if($count <= 0 || $key_length <= 0)
        die('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid parameters.');

    $hash_length = strlen(hash($algorithm, "", true));
    $block_count = ceil($key_length / $hash_length);

    $output = "";
    for($i = 1; $i <= $block_count; $i++) {
        // $i encoded as 4 bytes, big endian.
        $last = $salt . pack("N", $i);
        // first iteration
        $last = $xorsum = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true);
        // perform the other $count - 1 iterations
        for ($j = 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
            $xorsum ^= ($last = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true));
        }
        $output .= $xorsum;
    }
    return substr($output, 0, $key_length);
}
```

And the results are:

```
PHP
PASS: FFo9WjYztlOzuffOddN/Jbg6HBOUku+lxSUKvJuWCRCsYe+1Tgbb8Ob4FtxumMal
SALT: rGHvtU4G2/Dm+BbcbpjGpQ==

.NET
PASS: 5SyOX+Rbclzvvit3MEM2nBRaPVo2M7ZTs7n3znXTfyW4OhwTlJLvpcUlCryblgkQ
SALT: 5SyOX+Rbclzvvit3MEM2nA==
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you could try this perhaps, http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Thanks, switching it for the custom method resulted in the exact same result, which is great that it simplified the code, but still have the same problem unfortunately.

Comment: Well, one problem is that you're printing `$iv` and labelling it SALT.  Next I'll question of strlen is appropriate. But the harder to see one is that .NET turns the string password into bytes via UTF-8. If PHP  uses UCS-2 or UTF-16 then your binary HMAC keys aren't the same.

Comment: as @bartonjs - mentioned, I would add for charsets you may find this useful http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix internal coding didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up getting it working using the https://github.com/defuse/password-hashing libraries, with some minor changes match the format of hashes I was working with database I'm importing.

But my main problem was with these lines where I'm trying to get a key out of a hash.

```
$dev = pbkdf2('sha1', '#0zEZcD7uNmv', $mySalt, 10000, 48, true);
$key = substr($dev, 0, 32); //Keylength: 32
$iv = substr($dev, 32, 16); // IV-length: 16
```

Changing it to the below, so that it is creating a hash hash that is 32 bits long and joining the returning hash to the salt fixed the issue.

```
$dev = pbkdf2('sha1', '#0zEZcD7uNmv', $mySalt, 10000, 32, true);
echo 'PASS: '.base64_encode($mySalt.$dev).'<br />';
```

With the output below now matching .NET:

```
PASS: 5SyOX+Rbclzvvit3MEM2nBRaPVo2M7ZTs7n3znXTfyW4OhwTlJLvpcUlCryblgkQ
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this post while searching for a way to migrate passwords from a legacy Asp.Net MVC application to Laravel.

For those interested in just comparing the generated hash (ie. for authentication purpose), please consider the following:

```php
function legacyHashCheck($hash, $password)
{
    $raw     = base64_decode($hash);
    $salt    = substr($raw, 1, 16);
    $payload = substr($raw, 17, 32);

    //new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, 1000).GetBytes(32)
    $check   = hash_pbkdf2('sha1', $password, $salt, 1000, 32, true);

    return $payload === $check;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems .NET core implements 2 formats now (2022).

Source
https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs

I needed to implement both for Laravel, so here is my contribution:

```
private function dotNetVerifyHash($hash, $password) {
    $version = ord($hash[0]);
    if ($version !== 0 && $version !== 1) {
        throw new \Exception('wrong version header: ' . $version);
    }
    if ($version === 0) {
        // Format: { 0x00, salt, subkey }
        $iterations = 1000;
        $subKeyLength = 32;
        $saltSize = 16;
        $salt = substr($hash, 1, $saltSize);
        $derived = hash_pbkdf2('sha1', $password, $salt, $iterations, $subKeyLength, true);
        $newHash = chr(0x00) . $salt . $derived;
    } else if ($version === 1) {
        // Format: { 0x01, prf (UInt32), iter count (UInt32), salt length (UInt32), salt, subkey }
        $unp = unpack('N3', substr($hash, 1, 12));
        $prf = $unp[1];
        $algorithm = '';
        switch ($prf) {
            case 0: $algorithm = 'sha1'; break;
            case 1: $algorithm = 'sha256'; break;
            case 2: $algorithm = 'sha512'; break;
            default: throw new \Exception('invalid prf: ' . $prf);
        }
        $iterations = $unp[2];
        $saltLength = $unp[3];
        $subKeyLength = 32;
        $salt = substr($hash, 13, $saltLength);
        $derived = hash_pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $iterations, $subKeyLength, true);
        $newHash = chr(0x01) . pack('N3', $prf, $iterations, $saltLength) . $salt . $derived;

    }
    return $hash === $newHash;
}
```

```
function dotNetCreateHash($password, $version = 1) {
    if ($version !== 0 && $version !== 1) {
        throw new \Exception('invalid version: ' . ord($hash[0]));
    }

    $salt = Str::random(16);
    if ($version === 0) {
        // Format: { 0x00, salt, subkey }
        $dev = hash_pbkdf2('sha1', $password, $salt, 1000, 32, true);
        return base64_encode(chr(0x00) . $salt . $dev);
    } else if ($version === 1) {
        // Format: { 0x01, prf (UInt32), iter count (UInt32), salt length (UInt32), salt, subkey }
        $algorithm = 'sha256';
        $prf = 1;
        $iterations = 10000;
        $saltLength = strlen($salt);
        $subKeyLength = 32;
        $derived = hash_pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $iterations, $subKeyLength, true);
        return base64_encode(chr(0x01) . pack('N3', $prf, $iterations, $saltLength) . $salt . $derived);
    }
}
```

And you can also extend Laravel with custom hasher:
https://gist.github.com/tonila/5719aea8ad57df6821d7acdd1ed4ef1a