# How to Generate ASP.NET Password using PHP

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

I have existing ap.net c# website is working with mysql database. now i am planning to create mobile app for that website for that API needs to be ready.
I am creating an API into PHP Laravel Framework. for RegistrationAPI needs to generate password.

Asp.net using its inbuilt library for generating password like

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("username", "password");
```

it automatically generates password in table called "webpages_membership"

**Note:** I am using same database which is used by aps.net working website. so my website will be in asp.net and api will be now in php.

I found MembershipModel class in php which is used to compare two password but it can not generate password.

```
<?php

/*
 * Author  : Mr. Juned Ansari
 * Date    : 15/02/2017 
 * Purpose : It Handles Login Encryption And Decryption Related Activities
 */

class MembershipModel {

    function bytearraysequal($source, $target) {
        if ($source == null || $target == null || (strlen($source) != strlen($target)))
            return false;
        for ($ctr = 0; $ctr < strlen($target); $ctr++) {
            if ($target[$ctr] != $source[$ctr])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    //This Function is Used to verifypassword
    function verifypassword($hashedPassword, $password) {

        $PBKDF2IterCount = 1000; // default for Rfc2898DeriveBytes
        $PBKDF2SubkeyLength = 32; // 256 bits       
        $SaltSize = 16; // 128 bits


        if ($hashedPassword == null) {
            return false;
            //show_error("hashedPassword is null");
        }
        if ($password == null) {
            return false;
            //show_error("Password is null");
        }

        $hashedPasswordBytes = base64_decode($hashedPassword);

        if (strlen($hashedPasswordBytes) != 48) {
            return false;
        }

        $salt = substr($hashedPasswordBytes, 0, $SaltSize);

        $storedSubkey = substr($hashedPasswordBytes, $SaltSize, $PBKDF2SubkeyLength);

        $generatedSubkey = $this->encript('sha1', $password, $salt, $PBKDF2IterCount, $PBKDF2SubkeyLength, true);

        return $this->bytearraysequal($storedSubkey, $generatedSubkey);
    }

    function encript($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output = false) {
        $algorithm = strtolower($algorithm);
        if (!in_array($algorithm, hash_algos(), true))
            return false;
        //show_error('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid hash algorithm.');
        if ($count <= 0 || $key_length <= 0)
            return false;
        //show_error('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid parameters.');

        $hash_length = strlen(hash($algorithm, "", true));
        $block_count = ceil($key_length / $hash_length);

        $output = "";
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $block_count; $i++) {

            $last = $salt . pack("N", $i);

            $last = $xorsum = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true);

            for ($j = 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
                $xorsum ^= ($last = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true));
            }
            $output .= $xorsum;
        }
        return substr($output, 0, $key_length);
    }

}
```

I have successfully created Login APi in PHP which is working fine using above class.

Comment: it might be a lot easier if you make an authentication part of the api in .net core and share the JWT with php.

Comment: I think if i am able to login uing phpapi then there should be some solution to generate password from php too. MembershipModel->verifypassword($hashedPassword, $password); is doing the same, here $hashedPassword is .net generated password, and $Password is my plain text password

Comment: C# Web-API or MVC might be a better choice for the API. Trying to reproduce C# functionality in PHP seems to me to be a major step backwards.

Comment: If you're doing the website in asp.net you should seriously consider using .Net for the API as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As all the comments are advising you, you’re *probably* doing it the hard way if you try to port this work over to PHP instead of letting PHP talk to the backend via some .NET component.

Nevertheless, if you’re set on porting it over, [the code for `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount()` is available on GitHub](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/WebMatrix.WebData/WebSecurity.cs#L318-L338). As you can see, it leans on the currently-configured membership provider's implementation of that method.

For `SimpleMembershipProvider`, [the implementation is very simple](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs#L573-L582). Here’s the important bit:

```
CreateUserRow(db, userName, values);
return CreateAccount(userName, password, requireConfirmation);
```

`CreateUserRow()` isn't very interesting or surprising, but `CreateAccount()` is responsible for the part I think you care about.

There are two parts that you'd need to port to PHP; `Crypto.HashPassword()` and `GenerateToken()`. Since you're calling `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount()` with only two parameters, you can ignore the `GenerateToken()` part (since `requireConfirmation` defaults to `false`).

[Here's the source code for `Crypto.HashPassword()`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Helpers/Crypto.cs#L88-L108). As per its comment, it performs:

> PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA1, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 1000 iterations.
>   (See also: SDL crypto guidelines v5.1, Part III)
>   Format: `{ 0x00, salt, subkey }`

…using the `System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes()` method.

Which leads us to [this directly related existing Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39544750/181495), which I *think* gives you what you want.